# Git Clones the Wrong Project

Tags: git, ssh, clone, bitbucket, openshift

I have an application on openshift, but I lost my src. I am trying to git clone from the ssh url given there, but when I run:

```
git clone ssh://...
```

I instead get one of my other projects that is setup with bitbucket. I assume this has something to do with my ssh keys, I have tried with little confidence different approaches to setup the config file, and generate another key and hook them up with openshift but to no avail.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that the key is the problem. Have you tried to ssh onto the machine? Are you getting to the right app? If so, the clone should work.

Comment: Openshift is a PaaS. I can't ssh into the machine per say, but it has a rhc client that let's you remotely login to the app using login credentials. However I would like to clone the src and make a few changes and push again. The reason that I think the key is the problem is that it clones one of my project from bitbucket.

Comment: Sure OpenShift is a PaaS and you don't ssh to a physical box, but you still can ssh to your app - https://www.openshift.com/developers/remote-access. Not all is driven by the rhc client.